# Is it possible to use generic parameter from another generic type

Tags: c#, generics

Is it possible to use generic parameter from another generic type, and infer the usage where used like this:

```
public class TypeA<T2> { }

public class TypeB<T1, T3, T2> where T3 : TypeA<T2> {}

public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        // works but kind of ugly...
        new TypeB<string, TypeA<int>, int>();

        // Is it possible somehow to infer the TypeAType from the implemented generic generic type so I can use it like this?
        new TypeB<string, TypeA<int>>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try it and see..

Comment: That is such a confusing naming. Can you try something less `TypeATypeBTypeA` like?

Comment: And, no, you cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, because C# does not support "generics on generics".

To explain what that means let me show you are more concrete example:

```cs
List<int> list = new List<int>();
HashSet<int> set = list.To<HashSet<int>>();
```

Here, the extension method `To()` is a magical piece of code that can convert one type of container into another.

Assuming C# supported this feature, one would naively try to define that method like so:

```cs
public static class EnumerableExtensions {
    public static TContainer<TItem> To<TContainer<TItem>>(
        this IEnumerable<TItem> source)
        where TContainer: IEnumerable {
        // magic
    }
}
```

This of course won't compile, because C# cannot parse a generic type parameter that is generic itself (`TContainer<TItem>`).

This whole concept is called *higher kinded polymorphism* (or *higher kinded types*) which C# doesn't support. It might in the future though and you can track progress in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/339).

There is a Nuget package called [LanguageExt](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext) which provides some higher-kinded types and if I recall correctly it does the same thing you do: explicitly declare the inner type so the type inference can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get close by introducing another type, with the same name, but with fewer constraints. To use in this situation;

```cs
public class TypeB<T1, T3, T2> where T3 : TypeA<T2> {}
public class TypeB<T1, T2> : TypeB<T1, TypeA<T2>, T2> {}

new TypeB<string, int>();
```

See also `UserStore<...>` from [AspNetCore.Identity](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/EntityFrameworkCore/src/UserStore.cs).

Comment: That doesn't do the same thing. You're forcing the use of `TypeA<T2>`, but the OP wants to allow derived versions of that type.

Comment: Correct. It's not possible to do what the OP asked, but you can get closer for cases where you don't care what type that is.