# Is it possible to simplify a generic type declaration that has its own generic type constraints?

Tags: c#, generics

Say I have these three generic class declarations:

```csharp
public interface IFoo<TId>
{
   TId Id { get; set; }
}
```

```csharp
public interface IBar<TFoo, TId, TIndex> where TFoo : IFoo<TId>
{
   TFoo First { get; set; }
   TFoo Second { get; set; }
   TIndex Index { get; set; }
}
```

```csharp
public interface ISystem<TFoo, TBar, TId, TIndex>
   where TFoo : IFoo<TId>
   where TBar : IBar<TIndex>
{
   ICollection<TFoo> Foos { get; private set; }
   ICollection<TBar> Bars { get; private set; }
   int CalculateSomething(TFoo foo);
}
```

I ended up with a lot of type declarations in `ISystem` to ensure all the constraints are met, e.g. implementing systems should only operate on specific implementations of `IFoo` and `IBar` within their systems. However, I am looking for ways to simplify the type declarations and look for solutions where some of the generic types can be inferred without needing to declare them as type parameters.

Note that `ISystem` implementations may refer to `IFoo.Id` and `IBar.Index` when implementing certain methods, like the `CalculateSomething()` in the example. A concrete implementation might have the following code:

```csharp
public class Foo : IFoo<Guid>
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : IBar<Foo, Guid, DateTimeOffset>
{
   public Foo First { get; set; }
   public Foo Second { get; set; }
   public DateTimeOffset Index { get; set; }
}

public class MockSystem : ISystem<Foo, Bar, Guid, DateTimeOffset>
{
   public ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; private set; }
   public ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; private set; }
   
   public int CalculateSomething(Foo foo)
   {
       // Foo.Id and Bar.Index referenced in this LINQ query
       var orderedBars = Bars.Where(b => b.First.Id == foo.Id || b.Second.Id == foo.Id)
                             .OrderBy(b => b.Index);

       int result = 0;
       foreach (var bar in orderedBars) 
       {
          // do calculations...
       }

       return result;
   }
}
```

**Questions**

Is it possible to:

1. Simplify `IBar`'s type declarations, e.g. `IBar<TFoo, TIndex>` while keeping it constrained to types of `IFoo<TId>`?
2. Simplify `ISystem`'s type declarations similarly? e.g. `ISystem<TFoo, TBar>` and let the compiler/runtime infer `TId` and `TIndex`? In the example class, I'd like to simplify the declaration into `public class MockSystem : ISystem<Foo, Bar>` so the rest of the program infers the `Id`s to be `Guid`s and infers the `Index`es to be `DateTimeOffset`s, without explicitly declaring them.

Comment: I wish. I guess you could use reflection but then you'd lose performance and compile time safety. As someone who came to C# after many years of C++, generics are very frustrating

Comment: You could write an empty interface like `IdHaver` where implementations are expected to have an ID function. Heck you could require they return object. But then again you lose type safety

Comment: This is what Higher Kinded Types are for (which C# doesn't have) where you could do `public interface IBar<TFoo, TId, TIndex> where TFoo : IFoo<>` so you don't care what `IFoo`'s type parameters are, just that `TFoo` implements *any* `IFoo` with some type parameters. See eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68998181/is-it-possible-to-use-generic-parameter-from-another-generic-type